# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Different's [third moderator election](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Ian C.] [image: patrix]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/876021/0).

Answer (score 7):

Congrats Ian, patrix! I look forward to seeing the ♦ next to your names, and for things to continue to be awesome with you on-board!

Now that we have an overseas mod, I'm going to have to find another time to fill in the moderation gaps. God knows most of my overnight flag handling was taking action on patrix, stuffe, bassplayer, and some other regulars' flags.

Comment: And after posting this and refreshing the page, they are!

Comment: Looks like I applied for a full time job :-)

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to the Stack Exchange team for running this election so smoothly and for working so hard to schedule the forum at a time that worked for so many of the candidates and site participants. Congratulations to the new mods. Thanks to all the candidates who ran.